# If I build my app deployment target set to 5.1 will it be compatible with iOS versions up to 7.0

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an app that I've built and tested on all iOS from 5.1 - 7.0.
If I build it with the deployment target set to 5.1 will it be compatible with all the IOS versions up to 7.0?
I noticed my app in the app store says compatible with iOS 7.0 though I want it to say it's compatible from 5.1 to 7.0.
By setting the deployment target to 5.1, will it say in the app store its compatible for all IOS versions from 5.1 - 7.0?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that should work. I was doing the same thing for a while.

Comment: Do I set the Nib files and leave them at 5.1 too?

Comment: Yes that is how I did it ;)

Comment: There is only one area I'm not sure though.  When you click on the project -> Target and then select the TAB Build settings.  Under the Architecture section it says BaseSDK -- says -- Latest IOS (IOS 7.0) is that going to effect the build?

Comment: Offhand I think that should be fine. BaseSDK is just what SDK you're actually using. So you're deploying for 5.1 but are using the iOS 7 SDK. Make sure to download the emulators for iOS 5 on up to do some testing as there will be some code that won't work on iOS 5 that will in 7. It's also a good idea to have an old iPod/iPhone/iPad with an older version of iOS around for testing. Happy Coding!